# python summing random integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#Use main and a void function named randnums.
#randnums takes no arguments and return none.
#The randnums function generates 6 random integers between 1 and 9.
#The total should be printed on a new line.
#Main should call the randnums function.

import random
total=0

def main():
    randnums()

def randnums():
    for nums in range(6):
        nums=random.randrange(1,10)
        total=total+nums
        print(nums,end=' ')
    print("\nThe total is:",total)

main()
```

I keep getting:

> local variable 'total' referenced before assignment

Or when `total=nums` it only shows the last `int` generated.

Can someone please explain to a beginner what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: FWIW, Python doesn't have void functions. If you don't specify a return value for a function it will return `None`. But I guess the assignment was originally written for another language...

Comment: BTW, it's probably a good idea to use 2 different names for the index of your `for` loop and your random number, rather than calling both of them `nums`. The code will run ok, because of how Python `for` loops work, but I suspect your teacher might not like it.

Comment: I thought a void function was a function that executes the statement within it then terminates? At least that's how Starting Out With Python defines it. And you're saying that I could put something like count in the for loop and it would still work? Thanks for the help.

Comment: In C (and various other languages), a void function is a function which doesn't return any value. But as I mentioned above it's not possible to create such a function in Python, so the closest equivalent is a function that always returns None.

Comment: But I'm not returning a value. I'm only calling the randnums function in main. Can you explain the deference so I understand better?

Comment: The Python interpreter sees that you aren't returning anything in your `randnums()` and `main()` functions and automatically returns `None` for you, because all Python functions **have to** return something. Generally, you can just ignore this `None` return value and pretend that they are void functions. But it's good to know that the None is there.

Comment: (cont) Let's say you accidentally did `print(randnums())` in your `main()`. Then when you run the program you'd see `None` printed on the last line, after the stuff that `randnums` prints. That would seem like a mysterious bug if you didn't know that `randnums()` returns `None`.

Comment: Oh I see, so with or with out the return statement functions are always passing something even if it's nothing. That clears it up for me, You've been a lot of help I appreciate it.

Comment: Not a problem. `None` is _not_ actually nothing. It's a special Python object with certain properties, but I can't really go into the details here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign to a variable inside a function, Python interprets it as local variable to that function. So when you do -

```
total=total+nums
```

You are actually trying to access the local variable `total` before defining it.

Based on your program, does not look like you need `total` to be a global variable, you can simply define it as 0 at the start of `randnums()` . Example -

```
def randnums():
    total = 0
    for nums in range(6):
```

Comment: Thanks great help! And now the += operator works too.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing problem because of variable scope.

```
total=total+nums
```

Notice that line, in your local scope, total doesn't exist but you are trying to get it's value and then add some `num` with it, which is the cause of your error.

If you really want to use it, use it like below:

```
global total
total=total+nums
```

So, that it recognises the global `total` variable.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I can't tell yet when I need to use a global variable or not yet. Hopefully I'll learn soon.

Comment: when you want to use a variable out of scope, you will use global. Your code would work right if we first assign some value to it rather then adding something with it's own, though it won't be logically correct.

Comment: I guess it's the seeing how large a scope I need that's the issue for me. Though I think I'm starting to get it now. If the total variable needed to be used in more than one function then a global variable would be more logical right? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @ErynEton: Yes, you _can_ use globals like that as a way of communicating between multiple functions, but you will learn better ways. Globals are ok for constants, but using them for variables leads to messy design that makes a program hard to modify, and experienced programmers (in most languages) try to avoid using them.

Comment: even for using in multiple functions, `global` should be avoided as possible. One thing you could do, take the variable as the function parameter and return it after you have done manipulation. This could be a way to avoid global.

Comment: Got it, best practice avoid global when possible. Thanks every one, you've been a big help!